# Why is Void() legal and ()() is not in Swift?

Tags: swift

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void) states:

```
typealias Void = ()
```

Why I can type:

```
let something = Void()
```

and it is fine.

If I type `let something = ()()`

it gives me an error. Why is this happening and is there any explanation?

Comment: The second is probably a syntax conflict. The compiler won't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I agree with Sulthan. And I can add that compiler only needs you to write:
**let something = ()**
And it gets your idea, no need to write the brackets twice. That is why it gives you an error, when you try do so.
If you type **Void()**, compiler first infers the type from the typealias **Void** and then it tries to execute it.